# uWSGI runs Django project from command line but not from Emperor uwsgi.service file

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, uwsgi

I am running a `virtualenv` with `Python3.6` on `Ubuntu 16.04` for my `Django` project using `uwsgi and NGINX`.

I have `uWSGI` installed globally and also in the `virtualenv.`

I can run my project from the command line using uWSGI within the env with

```
/home/user/Env/myproject/bin/uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/user/Env/myproject --chdir /home/user/myproject/src/myproject -w myproject.wsgi
```

and go to my domain and it loads fine.

However I am obviously running uWSGI in "Emperor mode" and when I set the service file up (along with NGINX) the domain displays `internal server error`.

The uWSGI logs trace to `--- no python application found ---`

I was having this problem when running

`uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/user/Env/myproject --chdir /home/user/myproject/src/myproject -w myproject.wsgi`

because it was using the global install uwsgi instead of the virtualenv one.

I changed my StartExec to the virtualenv uwsgi path but no luck.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, path error? Syntax error?

my `/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown user:www-data /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/home/user/Env/myproject/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: what does `--emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites` actually do? Where is your .ini file specified that tells uwsgi where the virtualenv is?

Answer (score 0):

Okay bit silly but it seems I ran `sudo systemctl stop uwsgi` and then `sudo systemctl start uwsgi` and it works now.

Comment: well you always need to restart systemd daemons when you change configuration. Silly indeed. ;)

Comment: @dirkgroten Too much computer time makes you silly and forgetful! Ta and appreciate the help Dirk :)